# Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the following structure:

```
Id Name
1  ABC
2  DEF
3  GHI
4  JKL
```

I have a list of ids:

```
ids = [2,3,4]
```

I need to create a new column in the dataframe and mark is as "Absent" if that id is not present in the list.

So I need the dataframe to look like this:

```
Id Name New_Col
1  ABC  Absent
2  DEF
3  GHI
4  JKL
```

I tried

```
df["new_col"] = ["absent" if df.id in ids else None]
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where` and `.isin()` for this kind of task.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ids = [2,3,4]

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Id'] = [1,2,3,4]
df['Name'] = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']

# selecting Ids in 'ids'
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['Id'].isin(ids),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method of a column and pass in an arbitrary function to instruct how each element in the new column needs to be constructed from each element in the old column.

Since the logic here is quite simple, we can use a lambda function to do this in the same line, without having to actually define a function:

```
ids = [2, 3, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'], 
})

df['new_col'] = df['Id'].apply(lambda x: "absent" if x not in ids else None)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   Id Name new_col
0   1  ABC  absent
1   2  DEF    None
2   3  GHI    None
3   4  JKL    None
```

(Note that I modified your if statement to `if x not in ids`, since it seems to be what you want based on the expected output)

Comment: i think numpy where is way faster than pandas apply

Comment: For a simple conditional, sure. Although performance does not seem to be an issue for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `map`:

```
ids = [2, 3, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'], 
})

df['new_col'] = df['Id'].map(lambda x: 'Absent' if x not in ds else None)
```

**Output:**

```
 Id Name new_col
 0   1  ABC  Absent
 1   2  DEF  None
 2   3  GHI  None
 3   4  JKL  None
```